# Increment by one with async await in node javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

How do i get the result from function 'three' to console.log in function 'one'?

```
one = async (number) => { 
        console.log(`we got ${number}`)
        await two(number)
        console.log('the number three should be here')
    }   

two = async (number) => {
    number++
    console.log(`I got ${number}`)
    await three(number)
}

three = (number) => {
    number++
    console.log(`last but not least ${number}`)
}

one(1)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. It is working correctly, and logs `we got 1` -> 
`I got 2` -> `last but not least 3` -> `the number three should be here`

Comment: use return and be aware that returning in an async function returns a Promise object. Both information should be sufficient to figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: Just consider what would happen if this code was not `async`. It wouldn't work either: JS is not a pass-by-reference language!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chained functions should `return` the incremented `number`. Note that since `two` is immediately returning the `three` call, there's no need for it to be `async`, feel free to convert it into a standard function that `return`s `three`'s `Promise`:

```js
one = async (number) => { 
        console.log(`we got ${number}`)
        const resTwo = await two(number)
        console.log('the number three should be here ' + resTwo)
    }   

two = (number) => {
    number++
    console.log(`I got ${number}`)
    return three(number)
}

three = (number) => {
    number++
    console.log(`last but not least ${number}`)
    return number;
}

one(1)
```

Comment: I love you! Thank you so much for the help it and the explanation! I hope you have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number = 0;
async function returnValue() {
  return Promise.resolve(number++);
}

returnValue(number).then(alert); // 0
returnValue(number).then(alert); // 1
returnValue(number).then(alert); // 2
returnValue(number).then(alert); // 3
```

We can explicitly return a promise